# zypak-wrapper error when building for Flatpak through electron-forge

Tags: electron, electron-forge, flatpak

I'm trying to migrate my app from `electron-builder` to `electron-forge`, because the latter supports Flatpak making. The sample app works without a hitch, but my real repository seems to have some problems.

I can package the app just fine, and the make<sup>[log](https://gist.github.com/SFR-git/10098c023ed08eac5caca9043391a567)</sup> doesn't throw any errors, but when running the app itself, this error appears:

```
/app/bin/zypak-wrapper: line 24: exec: my-program: not found
```

As far as I can see, there aren't any conflicting node modules, and the package.json itself doesn't really seem to change anything. I assume the problem is in my `main.js`, but I first need to understand what the error entails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with `zypak`, because it looked for the `name` specified in `package.json`, not taking into account the possibility of a `productName`.

Removing the `productName` fixed the problem, though I'm not sure how to replicate that behaviour now.

Comment: I just want to note for clarity that Zypak itself is given the program to run, it doesn't determine it itself. This would have been handled by electron-forge.